# Каr проверить загружаемый аудио файл на сервер?

Tags: php, javascript, html, аудио

Почему то в сети очень много Тем про загрузку картинок, а про аудио - ничего толкового нету. Ощущение что либо никто не пишет такое , либо все в платном секторе.
Допустип есть форма с input type='file'

```
<form name='upload' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='userfile'>
<input type='submit' name='doUpload' class='asb_f55' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

Как я понимаю как картинку передавать аудио файл нельзя. Но как тогда правильно это сделать?

И второй вопрос:
Допустим у меня есть простой обработчик который любой загружаемый файл закидывает в нужную директорию:

```
$uploaddir = 'content/tracks/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)
```

Как при загрузке проверить что это действительно mp3 или ogg файл и уже только потом сохранять в нужной папке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, первые несколько байт файла могут многое сказать о том что это за файл.

Называют это FILE SIGNATURES, вот таблица:

http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html.

То есть функцией http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php читаем байты сколько надо и сравниваем с допустимыми значениями. Этого может быть достаточно.

Так же можно использоват http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php.

```
<?php

  $safeMimeTypes = [
    'audio/ogg',
    'video/ogg',
    'audio/mpeg3',
    'audio/x-mpeg-3',
    'video/mpeg',
    'video/x-mpeg',
    'audio/mpeg'
  ];

  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);

  if (in_array($mime, $safeMimeTypes)) {
    // file is safe
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
  }

  finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: без вашей добавки файл закидывается. Но стоит мне что то добавить. итог- файла нет в директории :(

Comment: спасибо за подсказку про fread
$safeMimeTypes = [
    'ogg',
    'Ogg',
    'ID3',
    'id3',
    'mpeg',
    'mp3',
    'MP3'
  ];
$filename = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, 3);
fclose($handle);

if (in_array($contents, $safeMimeTypes)) {
    // file is safe
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
 echo'done';
  }else{
   echo'errors file';
  }

Comment: если можно что-то лучше жду предложений...

Comment: Может еще дадите подсказку как правильно переименовать загружаемый файл?

Comment: @Kamupo Я бы делал MD5 от id (того что в базе) например

Answer (score 1):

> Как я понимаю как картинку передавать аудио файл нельзя.

Можно. Никакой разницы браузеру нет, что он передает как файл.

> Как при загрузке проверить что это действительно mp3 или ogg файл

Браузер может в multipart/form-data добавить заголовок Content-Type, в котором будет mime-тип содержимого. А может и не добавить, тем более, что загружать файл к вам на сервер может и не браузер, а какой-нибудь скрипт. Если добавит, то он сделает это либо на основании расширения, либо на основании сигнатуры файла.

Точно так же можно действовать и на сервере — определить тип исходя из расширения файла, либо исходя из сигнатуры.

В последнем случае все в ваших руках, поэтому, как по мне, лучше всего по сигнатуре (заголовку) файла определять на сервере его тип, учитывая расширение (mp3/ogg). Если что-то не совпадает — выдавать ошибку.

Вот список сигнатур: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures